# Calculated column based on dropdown list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Hi I'm new in Sharepoint online.

I've created a custom list and some of its columns has drop down list.
 I want the next column fill with some values in checklist format based on the dropdown list.

## Example:

- Column A has a dropdown list
- Column B will automatically fill some values based on column's A list
- Column A list and its equivalent value to be filled in column B
- Sample 1 (data 1, data 2, data 3, data 4, data 5)
- Sample 2 (docs1, docs2, docs3, docs4, docs5)
- Sample done (exe1, exe2, exe3)

now if I choose dropdown list "`Sample 1`". In Column B the equivalent value will display in Check list format.
ex.

```
Column A | Column B           |  Column C
Sample 1 |[] data 1 [] data 3 | 
         |[] data 2 [] data 4 |
         |[] data 3           |
```

In column C the value that I will check will also display automatically.

Is this possible in Sharepoint online list??

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not all column types can be used in a calculated column. Your Column B says that it will automatically fill values (so im going to assume this is a lookup column), which is not a supported column in calculated columns.

[There is a workaround though,](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/01/sharepoint-not-all-column-types-can-be.html) which talks about how to bypass this limitation. It's worth a read as I've used this countless times